# HTML drop downs are not working on sharepoint online page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, angularjs

I am facing one strange issue with HTML drop downs.

We have deployed drop downs on SharePoint online pages using provided hosted add-in (MVC solution type).

We bind data to these drop-downs using Angular 1.0. Since last Friday when we click on these drop-downs (after page load), these drop-downs remain freeze (disabled), but when I hit `F12` or `Ctrl+/Ctrl-` and then click on these drop-downs, it start showing the values in the drop-down.

I am facing this issue only in Client VM's google chrome, its working fine in Client VM's IE and when we I am accessing the same page outside of Client's VM its not showing the freezing behavior and show values in the drop-down without hitting F12.

Chrome version in client VM is identical to my local machine.

There no deployment happened in past few weeks this issue start occurring all of a sudden.

Please suggest how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your suggestions. After investigating this issue more, i found that this issue occurred due to Chrome browser upgrade. Now post new browser everything start working fine as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have JavaScript enabled in your Chrome:

1.At the top right, click More More and then Settings.

2.At the bottom, click Show advanced settings.

3.In the "Privacy" section, click Content settings.

4.Select Allow all sites to run JavaScript (recommended) in the "JavaScript" section.

If the problem persists, you can refer to this similar situation:

[drop-down box binding doesn't work in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872674/angularjs-drop-down-box-binding-doesnt-work-in-google-chrome)